# Program to replace tabs with blanks

Tags: c

From my C university book 'The C Programming Language' by Brain W.Kernighan and Dennis M.Ritchie. Excercise 1 - 20.

> Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of
>       blanks to space to the next tab stop. 
>   Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every
>       n columns. Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABSTOP 8
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char s[], int len);

int main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0))
    {
        int i, j, count;

        count = 0;
        for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {
            if (line[i] == '\t')
            {
                for (j = 0; j < TABSTOP - count; ++j)
                {
                    putchar(' ');
                }

                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ++count;

                if (count >= TABSTOP)
                    count = 0;

                putchar(line[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int getline(char line[], int len)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < len - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        line[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

My concerns are that I didn't get the question right, did they mean that every time I see a tab in the input I need to put the corresponding amount of spaces instead of tabs?

Are there any flaws or bugs in the code?

I didn't understood what is a 'symbolic parameter', did they mean symbolic constant?

By 'n' did they mean what I did with the 'TABSTOP' symbolic constant?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is a valid question, but you seem to be asking the wrong questions. For example, you can't be asking for an explanation of the question here. If you believe to the best of your knowledge that your code is correct, then remove all the comments not about getting a Code Review.

Answer (score 5):

### Headers and Names

- You are using the `system` function that is declared in `stdlib.h` but you don't `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- The name `getline` is already taken by many C implementations for an extension to the standard library's I/O functions. You shouldn't use it for your own function names.

### Program structure

Your program basically consists of the `main` function. While simple it is, this is not a very modular design and in particular hostile to unit testing. I suggest you decouple the I/O logic from the tab expansion logic. Have one function read the input line-by-line and for each line it reads, make it call another function that processes the line and places the results in a separate buffer. It could look like this:

```
size_t
expand_tabs(int tabwidth, const char * input, char * output, size_t length);
```

The first function then outputs that buffer. This way you can, for example, unit test `expand_tabs` with an array of strings.

Don't put

```
system("pause");
```

in your programs.  I know many tutorials targeted at people using the Windows operating system suggest this but it is poor advice. If your program is done, make it exit. If this causes your terminal emulator to close the window before you wanted it to, fix the way you use the terminal emulator, not your program.

### I/O Handling

Avoid character-based I/O.  It's slow and painful. Instead of your hand-rolled `getline` function, you could have used the standard library `fgets` function. From [its man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than *size* characters from *stream* and stores them into the buffer pointed to by *s*.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> `fgets()` returns *s* on success, and `NULL` on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

This is just what your `getline` function does but faster and cleaner.

Never use the seemingly simpler `gets` function.  It is broken and C11 removed it from the standard library.

While using stack-allocated buffers like

```
char line[MAXLINE];
```

is fast, the hard-coded limit is a little awkward. You actually took care to make your program process files with lines longer than `MAXLINE` correctly too. Congratulations for that. Another option would be to use a dynamically allocated buffer. If your implementation has it, the aforementioned [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) function comes in handy, here. If you are following the book, I'm not sure if you've already learned about dynamic memory yet, though.

### Style

While declaring functions as

```
int my_getline(char s[], int len);
```

is valid syntax, it is misleading because the first argument actually is a *pointer* and not an *array*.  So I prefer the (functionally equivalent)

```
int my_getline(char * s, int len);
```

syntax.

As long as you want to use `MAXLINE` to create an array, it needs to be a macro, unfortunately.  For `TABSTOP` there is no such need. Avoid macros if possible. Here, a `static const int` would have been perfectly fine. Note that in the `expand_tabs` function suggested above, I'm even passing it as a parameter so it doesn't depend on global constants. Of course, the constant has to be coded at *some* point in your program.

Comment: How do you calculate the length of the output-buffer? And if the input-buffer is of fixed length, how do you pass the column-index to the next iteration? Why is the hard-coded buffer-size awkward, especially more than possible allocation-failures? Besides, I disagree about `[]` in function-parameters, they are good for marking that apointer to the beginning of an array is expected, not to a single object.

Comment: @Deduplicator You could dynamically reallocate the output buffer as `getline` does for the input buffer. An output buffer size of `tabwidth * strlen(input) + 1` would guarantee that you'll never have to reallocate but it would be quite wasteful and not very pretty.

Comment: Well, I wanted to nudge you into expanding on your proposed transformation-function `expand_tabs`: What are the implementation-considerations, inputs, outputs and the like?

Comment: @Deduplicator I would have done that on SO but I thought that re-writing code was considered off-topic on Code Review.  Is this not so?

Answer (score 4):

#### includes and symbol-names

[5gon12eder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/u/67456) is right about the [missing header for `system` and many implementations claiming the symbol `getline`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106889).
Just want to add that if the implementation defining `getline` interferes with you defining it however you want, it's non-conforming, for whatever that's worth.

#### Forward-declarations

Don't repeat yourself.
If there are no circular dependencies, omit any forward-declarations and instead define before use.

The above should *not* be as a vote against using multiple source-files and declarations in included header-files where the projects size merits that.
Though even (or especially) in that case, just like there is only one definition, there should only be a single declaration.

#### `system("pause");`

As 5gon12eder said, prune this. If your terminal quits before you see the output, fix how you call your program.

#### `getline`

Let's *for the moment* pretend reading each separate line into a buffer and then transforming that was a good idea, and there was no standard-library function for that.

Well, you should avoid pushing so much into a for-loop's condition, even though it technically works.
Also, slightly changing the loop allows merging the deferred storing of the newline.
I also added a debug-mode precondition-check (`#include <assert.h>`):

```
int getline(char line[], int len) {
    assert(line && len > 0);
    int c = 0, i = 0;
    while(c != '\n' && i < len - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF)
        line[i++] = c;
    line[i] = 0;
    return i;
}
```

#### How big is a tabstop?

People use tabstops of different lengths, the classic 8 being most common, 4 following quite a long step behind, 2 also being seen, and that was nearly everything observed.
So allow the user to override the default.

#### I/O and Algorithm

Here we get to the heart of it.

One *could* go *byte-at-a-time* (just drop `getline` and use `getchar` / `putchar` directly), even though that's incredibly inefficient.
There are also disadvantages to going *line-at-a-time* (using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), `gets` is always an error): Lines can be too long for your buffer (and simply growing the buffer is no good), or too short for efficiency (degenerates to byte-at-a-time) and you don't need the whole line anyway.
The optimal unit of work is *block-at-a-time* (using [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread), [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite), and reasonably-sized buffers (powers of two)). Beside being more efficient (single-pass, aside from newline-transformation if neccessary on the implementation), it also handles embedded 0-bytes gracefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFFSIZE (1<<11)
#define MAXTABSTOP 64

int main(int c, char* argv[]) {
    char input[BUFFSIZE];
    char output[BUFFSIZE+MAXTABSTOP];
    int n = 0, i = -1, o = 0, t = 0, tabstop = 8;
    if(c > 1) {
        tabstop = strtol(argv[1], argv, 10);
        if(**argv || tabstop < 1 || tabstop > MAXTABSTOP)
            tabstop = 8;
    }
    for(;;) {
        if(n == ++i && (i = 0) == (n = fread(input, 1, BUFFSIZE, stdin))) {
            fwrite(output, 1, o, stdout);
            return 0;
        }
        switch(input[i]) {
        case '\t':
            if(!t)
                t = tabstop;
            while(t--)
                output[o++] = ' ';
            break;
        case '\n':
            t = -1;
            // FALLTHRU
        default:
            t = (t+1) % tabstop;
            output[o++] = input[i];
        }
        if(o >= BUFFSIZE) {
            fwrite(output, 1, o, stdout);
            o = 0;
        }
    }
}
```